# Prolog - ASP 'not' to Prolog negate

Tags: prolog, logic-programming, negate, answer-set-programming

I have an example problem in Answer Set Programming (ASP). When I try to make the equivalent code in Prolog, I keep getting stuck with the `not` blocked.

This is the ASP code:

```
road(berlin,potsdam).
road(potsdam,werder).
road(werder,brandenburg).
road(X,Y) :- road(Y,X).

blocked(werder,brandenburg).

route(X,Y) :- road(X,Y), not blocked(X,Y).
route(X,Y) :- route(X,Z), route(Z,Y).

drive(X) :- route(berlin,X).

#show drive/1
```

The answer is: `drive(potsdam)`, `drive(werder)`, `drive(berlin)`.

In Prolog, I initially thought it would be as simple as changing the `not` to `\+`. When I query `drive(X).`, it recursively generates the `X = potsdam` answer. I know that Prolog and ASP work differently but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `road(X,Y) :- road(Y,X).` This will recurse forever if there is no match among the facts:

```
is road(X,Y)?
is road(Y,X)?
is road(X,Y)?
is road(Y,X)? 
.....
```

You can replace the predicate:

```
road(X,Y) :- road(Y,X).
```

with

```
road(X,X).
```

and add:

```
reachable(X,Y):-
     road(X,Y)
  ;  road(Y,X).
```

and modify:

```
route(X,Y) :- road(X,Y), \+ blocked(X,Y).
```

to:

```
route(X,Y) :- reachable(X,Y), \+ blocked(X,Y).
```

Comment: If you add road(werder,city). it does not give as a result city ,as it should.

Comment: Your right, was to quick on the update. The previous version still works but gives duplicate answers.